# How to change working directory in asynchronous futures in R

Tags: r, future

I am trying to change working directory in a future processor, carry out some operations, and exit. The problem is I am not able to set a working directory.

The following toy example works fine

```
library(future)
dirNames <- as.character(c(1:4))
sapply(dirNames, function(x) if(!dir.exists(x)) dir.create(x))
plan(multiprocess, workers=2)
b <- list()

for(i in seq_along(dirNames)){
  sleeptime <- 10
  if(i > 3) sleeptime <- 50
  a <- future({
    # setwd(dirNames[i])
    Sys.sleep(sleeptime)
    return(2)
  })
  print(i)
  b[[dirNames[i]]] <- a
}
lapply(b, resolved)
lapply(b[1:2], value)
lapply(b, value)
```

**but if I uncomment line 11** then I get following error when running the code

> Error in setwd(dirNames[i]) : cannot change working directory

How can I change working directory successfully?

Comment: what is multiprocess, plan doing ?

Comment: Not familiar with `future`, but can you just use the parent directory as the working directory and specify paths from that directory?

Comment: ```future``` is an R package that aids parallel computation. I am trying to source R scripts from the new directory and these R scripts contain paths based on the location of the R script. So, if I source the R script from current working directory (w/o changing the working directory) then the paths in the R script are not recognized. Hence, the reason why I want to change the working directory to these R scripts before sourcing them.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution while playing around with the script.

```
library(future)
dirNames <- as.character(c(1:4))
sapply(dirNames, function(x) if(!dir.exists(x)) dir.create(x))
plan(multiprocess, workers=2)
b <- list()

for(i in seq_along(dirNames)){
  sleeptime <- 10
  if(i > 3) sleeptime <- 50
  a <- future({
    currDir <- getwd()
    on.exit(setwd(currDir))
    setwd(dirNames[i])
    Sys.sleep(sleeptime)
    return(2)
  })
  print(i)
  b[[dirNames[i]]] <- a
}
lapply(b, resolved)
lapply(b[1:2], value)
lapply(b, value)
```

I believe that the workers working directory once set in the first few iterations remains permanently set to new directory for remaining iterations and hence future paths (with reference to old directory) do not work.