# r - downloading multiple files into separate subfolders with foreach - error with setwd

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach, furrr

I have the following code which downloads a link into the appropriate folder > subfolder. This code works great although it is very slow. I have a couple of hundred .zip files that I am attempting to download so that they can be processed.

Within the folders and subfolders structure of country data, some countries may have 1 subfolder while others may have multiple subfolders.

In order to mimic the existing conditions, I am also enclosing some dummy code below:

```
library("furrr")
library("curl")

country.year.dir <- c("/test/GB/GB_2010", "/test/GB/GB_2014", "/test/GN/GN_2016",
"/test/GY/GY_2000", "/test/GY/GY_2006-2007", "/test/GY/GY_2014")

my.country.names_DTs$URL <- c("https://GB 2010 Datasets.zip", 
"https://GB 2014 Datasets.zip", "https://GN 2016 Datasets.zip", 
"https://GY 2006-2007 Datasets.zip", "https://GY 2014 Datasets.zip")

my.country.names_DTs$URL_Clean <- c("https://GB_2010_Datasets.zip", 
"https://GB_2014_Datasets.zip", "https://GN_2016_Datasets.zip", 
"https://GY_2006-2007_Datasets.zip", "https://GY_2014_Datasets.zip")

for(i in seq(country.year.dir)){
setwd(country.year.dir[i])
                    
my.shortcut.2 <- curl_download(my.country.names_DTs[i]$URL, destfile = 
my.country.names_DTs[i]$URL_Clean)
}
```

I searched for ways to speed up the process to download links, and I came across this answer: [How can I configure future to download more files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337477/how-can-i-configure-future-to-download-more-files)

I have modified that code to fit my unique situation; however, the code below does not work. I receive an error message.

```
download_template <- function(.x) {
for(i in seq(country.year.dir)) {
    my.shortcut.2 <- curl_download(url =
my.country.names_DTs[i]$URL, destfile = my.country.names_DTs[i]$URL_Clean)
}
}

download_future_core <- function() {
plan(multiprocess)
future_map(my.country.names_DTs$URL, download_template)
}

download_future_core()
```

Is there anyway to speed up the code that works so that the same functionality can be kept?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Instead of attempting to use `furrr`, I rewrote the function using `foreach`. The revised code is below:

```
library("foreach")
library("curl")
import::from(future, plan, cluster)
import::from(doParallel, registerDoParallel)
import::from(snow, stopCluster)
import::from(parallel, makeCluster, detectCores)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())

plan(strategy = "cluster", workers = cl)

registerDoParallel(cl)

download_MICS_files <- foreach(i = seq(country.year.dir_MICS)) %dopar% {

currDir <- getwd()
on.exit(setwd(currDir))
setwd(country.year.dir_MICS[i])

MICS_downloaded <- curl_download(my.country.names_MICS_DTs[i]$URL, destfile = 
my.country.names_MICS_DTs[i]$URL_Clean)

}
```

As I was (and am still getting) this error message from the `foreach` loop:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "cannot change working directory"
```

I searched for help regarding setwd and `foreach` loops. I came across the following answer:

[How to change working directory in asynchronous futures in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408736/how-to-change-working-directory-in-asynchronous-futures-in-r)

and I used a couple of lines from that answer, but I am still getting the same error message.

What's the best way to navigate between the working directories so that the `foreach` construct works as well as the plain for loop with the setwd() error message?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this `?curl::multi`

Comment: @ekoam  Thank you for your suggestion, but I rewrote the function using `foreach` instead of `furrr`. The issue is not downloading the multiple files at once per se, but it's getting the right files in the right subfolders.